# Import .bak file into SQL Server from windows cmd-line: Syntax error

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a `.bak` file and want to import it back again into SQL Server from a Windows cmd prompt.

I tried:

```
sqlcmd -S "MyComputer\MyServer" -U myuser -P mypass -d database 
       -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\myfiles\mybackup.bak"
```

But the result is only:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 3917 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\myfiles\mybackup.bak'.

Restoring the same file via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio works without problems. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't "import" a backup file, you restore it. It's a binary file, not a script. Restoring a backup overwrites the database. Unless you have a script file with the **extremely unfortunate** extension `.bak` ?

Comment: `-i` is short for "input", not "import". As in, "use this file which is supposed to contain SQL statements as my input". Needless to say, a backup file isn't a text file with statements and you'll need an explicit `RESTORE` command if you want to use `sqlcmd` (you can have this `RESTORE` scripted if you use SSMS and look for the "script" button).

Comment: Thanks for your replys. So whats the way then to restore the database via cmd-line from the .bak-file?

Comment: Even if `.bak` is actually a SQL script, we can't guess what it does

Comment: @Werner if you don't know that, stop whatever you're doing and find out. Once you overwrite the database, it's gone. Read the docs, don't just type commands.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax: SqlCmd -E -S "MyComputer\MyServer" –Q “RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK=’C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\myfiles\mybackup.bak'”

Comment: @Werner do you understand what that does though? You can't restore directly from the command line. `-Q` specified a query to execute, in this case `RESTORE DATABASE FROM DISK=...`. It's SQL Server that executes the restore, not `sqlcmd`. If SQL Server can't see that path it will fail